# Global directives for Plot-options

Tags: plotting, formatting

How can I set an option like

```
TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]
```

notebook-wide, so that it is used for any `Plot` and `ListPlot` in my notebook?

Comment: `SetOptions[{Plot, ListPlot}, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]];`

Comment: This question seems to be well received, even though `SetOptions` could have been found in the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default:

```
GraphicsRow[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], ListPlot[Range[6]]}]
```

[image]

To set global options:

```
SetOptions[{Plot, ListPlot}, TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]];
```

then

```
GraphicsRow[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], ListPlot[Range[6]]}]
```

[image]